# Plotting equations of motion of a baseball

Tags: differential-equations, physics

So I went through the physics of a baseball and I got the exact same equations as shown [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sjmoura/files/ME170.pdf) on page 8.  I input all of the same parameters into my code, and I don't get the same thing.  Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
ClearAll[t, x, y, z];
parms = {Cd -> .3, Cm -> 1, ωx -> -1500, ωy -> 0, ωz -> 0, m -> .142, ρ -> 1.225, A -> .608, R -> .22};
term = Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2];
eq1 = m x''[t] == -(1/2 ρ*A*Cd*x'[t]*term) + (4 π*ρ*R^3*(ωy*z'[t] - ωz*y'[t]));
eq2 = m y''[t] == -(1/2 ρ*A*Cd*y'[t]*term) + (4 π*ρ*R^3*(ωz*x'[t] - ωx*z'[t]))-9.81*m;
eq3 = m z''[t] == -(1/2 ρ*A*Cd*z'[t]*term) + (4 π*ρ*R^3*(ωx*y'[t] - ωy*x'[t]));
ic1 = {x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0};
ic2 = {y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 1.6};
ic3 = {z'[0] == 90, z[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, ic1, ic2, ic3} /. parms, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 1}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{z[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, .01}, PlotRange -> 1.8]
```

This should be the same as the bottom image on page 13.

Comment: Subscript[\[Omega], y] is missing the assignment rule

Comment: it should be 0 there

Comment: can't read your code with all this subscript this and subscript that. Sorry. Can't read code, can't help.

Comment: When I copied it from mathematica that is how it copied over :(

Comment: I know that offcourse. But the problem is that when copying it back from here to my notebook, the subscripts stay in the long form. Hence impossible to read the code.  That is why it is not good idea to use it subscripts in code. Become hard to move around as plain text code.

Comment: @Nasser I took care of that ... this time. The OP is expected to do this himself the next time

Comment: thank you @belisarius for doing that

Comment: @yankeefan11 For starters, you should check the units (MPH and RPM aren't MKS units, are they?)

Comment: All of my code is in metric.  The initial value of z should be about half of what it currently is (200 mph, not happening).  But it doesnt matter, I get weird shapes for all initial velocities

Comment: what is the unit of the omega parameters? They seem to be the most troublesome to get right.

Comment: If my dimensional analysis is correct you should express the omega params in 1/seconds, while rpm are in 1/minutes. So 1500 rpm will turn into 25 rps. Try 25 or 0.707 * 25

Comment: Also, if A is the area of the ballsection, 0.68 square meters is a beach ball (the ones you have to inflate like a life preserver). Try 0.0068, instead. And if R is its radius, R=.22 meters is a bit too much for a baseball too (it's a bit to much for a basketball, too). Try 0.035.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you have some errors on your constants:

```
ClearAll[t, x, y, z];
parms = {Cd -> .3, Cm -> 1, ωx -> 0, ωy -> 0, ωz -> -1500/60, m -> .142, ρ -> 1.225, 
         A -> Pi .03^2, R -> .03};
term = Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2];
eq1 = m x''[t] == -(1/2 ρ*A*Cd*x'[t]*term) + (4 π*ρ*R^3*(ωy*z'[t] - ωz*y'[t]));
eq2 = m y''[t] == -(1/2 ρ*A*Cd*y'[t]*term) + (4 π*ρ*R^3*(ωz*x'[t] - ωx*z'[t])) - 9.81*m;
eq3 = m z''[t] == -(1/2 ρ*A*Cd*z'[t]*term) + (4 π*ρ*R^3*(ωx*y'[t] - ωy*x'[t]));
ic1 = {x'[0] == 90, x[0] == 0};
ic2 = {y'[0] == 0,  y[0] == 1.6};
ic3 = {z'[0] == 0,  z[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, ic1, ic2, ic3} /. parms, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 3}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, .2}, AspectRatio -> 1,
               PlotRange -> {{0, 18}, {0, 1.7}}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: area = pi * r^3? :-)

Comment: @Peltio You know, it's the _New Kind of Geometry_ :D

Comment: Ehehe, now you can lower the speed to reasonable values too and try a curveball and a screwball. A ParametricPlot3D in scale might show the actual trajectory in space.

Comment: @belisarius You all gonna end in Wolfram Hell for those jokes :P

Comment: @Kuba You don't know how many times a day I feel like being already there :)

Comment: @belisarius alternating between limbo, purgatory and hell, tho.